# Searching for "2038" (without quotes) redirects to a particular question instead of executing a search

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, search

Am I going crazy?  Searching for "2038" (without quotes) redirects me to [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2038/commandline-gstreamer-player), whereas searching for "2037" or "2039" (again, without quotes) actually executes a search.  Searching for "2038" WITH quotes properly executes a search (or, if you are a C programmer, then that would be "\"2038\"" :-)).  I have not really tested to see if this problem happens with other numbers, but this particular number is troubling because of the Y2K38 problem.  I am pretty sure that this is a bug, could I get a confirmation from another user or a fix from an admin?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That question has ID 2038; searching for questions by ID has worked [for some time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/43931/145982). Posts 2037 and 2039 are both answers, so it doesn't automatically redirect to the question page, but any question ID should work (for example, searching for [1141 here on meta](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=1141)).

Quoting it returns normal results because a few weeks ago we switched to a [new search engine](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160100/a-new-search-engine-for-stack-exchange), and now quoted phrases are exact matches, so it prevents the search engine from interpreting the number as an ID

Comment: Would it be appropriate to add to the top of the question a note _If you arrived here by searching for 2038, [click here to search for "2038"](http://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=%222038%22)_ ?